# Switching views when a tab is clicked in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I know this question has been asked and I kind of know what I need to do; I just need a small push to get me over the finish line. Here is what I have.

Android app with two tabs and I need to switch fragment view based on which tab is selected. Here is my code so far.

Main Activity

```
    @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // This is called when a tab is selected.
    Log.d(app, "Tab: " + tab.getPosition());

    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            Test1Fragment test1Fragment = new Test1Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, test1Fragment);
            break;
        case 1:
            //Intent i = new Intent(this, Test1.class);
            //startActivity(i);
            Test2Fragment test2Fragment = new Test2Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, test2Fragment);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
    }
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // This is called when a previously selected tab is unselected.
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // This is called when a previously selected tab is selected again.
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
```

I just do not know how to inflate the fragments. This code will show test1Fragment when tab one is clicked but test1Fragment still shows when tab two is clicked. I know I need to remove and replace. I just don't know how to do it. Please help

Comment: May be this article will help you. http://sapandiwakar.in/replacing-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

First thing i see, is that you are missing a commit() for completing the transaction.

Follow this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gimo5cZler8
And it's followup tutorial , implementing viewpager is also interesting.

It helped me to succesfully implement it in my application.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJ178Z8U7FM

This is the interesting part for you:

```
package com.example.multiplefrag;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.fragmentexample.R;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
    Fragment frag;
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction;

    public MenuFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_multi, container, false);

        frag = new KoalaFragment();
        fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,frag);
        fragTransaction.commit();

        Button btnKoala = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonKoala);
        Button btnPenguin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPenguin);
        Button btnOther = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOther);
        btnKoala.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                frag = new KoalaFragment();
                fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,frag);
                fragTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        btnPenguin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                frag = new PenguinFragment();
                fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,frag);
                fragTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        btnOther.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                frag = new OtherFragment();
                fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,frag);
                fragTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```